# Is there in locale/codecvt a proper facet to test for character specifics

Tags: c++11, unicode, locale, codecvt

Well in C++ codecvt/locale library is there a proper facet one could use to test if a character "is" something? IE to test if a character is any form of linebreaking character, or represents a numeric or a whitespace etc etc?

Or would one have to go manually/use rely on regex for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the `std::ctype` facet and its `is` method:

```
std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(std::locale()).is(std::ctype_base::digit, '9');
```

The available classification masks can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype_base).

There isn't a classification category for line breaking characters; for that, you'll need to use ICU `u_getIntPropertyValue` with the `UCHAR_LINE_BREAK` and check for `U_LB_MANDATORY_BREAK`, etc.